# Design and implement a Purse Class, Coin Class, and a driver by working with Arrays of objects and Classes

Tags: java

Purse Class:
a. There will be an array of Coin objects (using the Coin Class) and a parallel array of integer counts. There should be single variables that hold the count of Coin objects added so far, total number of coins and total value in the purse.

b. The constructor should set the dimension of the arrays to be 10 and set the single instance variables to zero.

c. Three accessors are needed: count of Coin objects added so far, the total count of all the coins, and the total value in the purse.

d. The toString() method should output the values for each Coin in the Purse along with its count and value (count * Coin Value).

e. There will be an add() method that takes in both a Coin object and a count of how many are being added to the Purse. Place the Coin and count in the next available position in the parallel arrays. The total count and value in the purse should be incremented.

I wrote the Coin Class and Purse Class, but there is a glitch in the Purse Class because it is not counting the type of coins or the number of coins properly.

Coin Class:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
public class Coin {

  private String name; //instance variable (a)
  private double value;
  private int year;

   //Default Constructor (b)
   public Coin(){
     String name = " ";
     double value = 0.0;
     int year = 0;
   }

  //Parametrized Constructor (c)
  public Coin(String name, double value, int year){
  this.name = name;
  this.value = value;
  this.year = year;
  }
  //Accessors(d)

 public String getName(){
 return this.name; 
 }

 public double getValue(){
 return this.value; 
 }

 public int getYear(){
 return this.year; 
 }

 //Mutators(d)
 public void setName(String newName){
 this.name = newName;
 }

 public void setValue(double newValue){
 this.value = newValue;
 checkValue();
 }

 public void setYear(int newYear){
 this.year = newYear;
 checkYear();
 }

 //Helper Method(e)
 public void checkValue(){
   if (value < 0.0){
    this.value = 0.0;
   }
  }

 //Helper Method (f)
 public void checkYear(){
   if((year >= 1900) || (year <= 2018)){
     this.year = 0;
   }
}
 //toString method (g)
 public String toString(){
 String str = "Coin:" + this.name;
 NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

   str += "\tvalue:" + fmt.format(this.value);
   str += "\tyear:";

   if (year!= 0)
    str += this.year;
  else
  {
    str += "Unknown";
   }
return str;
 }
}
```

Purse Class:

```
    import java.text.NumberFormat;
    public class Purse {
     //a
    private Coin[] coins;
    private int[]counts;

    private int coinCount;
    private double totalValue;
    private int totalCount;

    //b (Constructor)
    public Purse(){
    coins = new Coin[10];
    counts = new int[10];
    coinCount = 0;
    totalValue = 0.0;
    totalCount = 0;
    }

    //c 
    public int getCoinCount(){
    return coinCount;
    }

    public int getTotalCount(){
    return totalCount;
    }

    public double getTotalValue(){
    return totalValue;
    }

    //d (toString() method)
    public String toString(){
    String result = " "; 
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

      for(int i = 0; i<coinCount; i++){
        result += fmt.format(counts[i] * coins[i].getValue())+coins[i]+counts[i];
      }
      return result;

    }

    //e
    public void addCoin(Coin c,int n){
    coins[coinCount]=c;
    counts[coinCount]=n;
    coinCount++;
    totalCount += n;
    totalValue += (n * c.getValue());
    }
    }
```

Driver:

```
public class CoinDriver {
public static void main(String[] args) { 
   Coin p = new Coin("Penny", 0.01, 2001);
   Coin n = new Coin("Nickel", 0.05, 2001);
   Coin d = new Coin("Dime", 0.10, 2001);
   Coin q = new Coin("Quarter", 0.25, 2001);
   Coin l = new Coin("Loonie", 1.00, 2001);
   Coin t = new Coin ("Toonie", 2.00, 2001);
  Purse purse = new Purse();
  System.out.print("There are: " +purse.getCoinCount() + "types of coins, a total of:" + purse.getTotalCount()+ "coins, worth:" + purse.getTotalValue());
  System.out.print(purse);

  purse.addCoin(p,3);
  purse.addCoin(n,5);
  purse.addCoin(d,7); 
  System.out.print("There are: " +purse.getCoinCount() + "types of coins, a total of:" + purse.getTotalCount()+ "coins, worth:" + purse.getTotalValue());

  System.out.print(purse);
  } 
}
```

The final Results should include the number of coins in the purse, the types of coins (total of), and the value of all the coins.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  "There is a glitch" doesn't tell us much about the problem.  This is a good opportunity for you to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  With a debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes, observing its exact runtime behavior and the changing runtime values of your variables.  When you do this, where specifically does a problem first occur?  Which specific operation produces an unexpected result?  What were the values at the time?  What result did you observe?  What result did you expect?  Why?

Comment: The output could stand to be formatted better, but it appears correct to me.  Which part of the output do you believe is incorrect?

Comment: When I run my program and add the same type of coins to my "Purse" it counts both the coins as different types. For example, when I added two different amounts for the coin penny, a dime, and a nickel to my purse the output was "4 types of coins"; however, it should be 3 because I added two of the same type.                                
 That is what I meant by "glitch" sorry for the confusion.